# Scripts like ideone.com and codepad.org

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, sandbox

Are there any auto compiling scripts like the ones used at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) and [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/) available?

(preferably open source, and which execute the code in a safe environment.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that they have special "autocompiling scripts". They could just be using normal compilers under a virtual machine for safety.

Or they could have developed something custom (Like Google app engine)

**Update:**

Apparently they are using [normal compiler packages](http://ideone.com/faq) by Gentoo.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use [Ideone API](http://ideone.com/api)?